# How can I get ubuntu network interface stats in the terabyte range?

Tags: linux-networking, ifconfig, ubuntu-20.04

When I query my server's network interface stats using either `ifconfig` or `ip -s` they're limited to 999GB and then roll over to 0GB, starting again. Is it possible to change the configuration somehow to allow stats logging in the terabyte range? Or use a different logging tool? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ uname -p
x86_64

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Many thanks.

Edit to add requested information. `enp4s0` is the LAN side of my firewall and the total has only recently just reset back to 0GB. I'll provide updates in due course.

**ifconfig output:**

```
$ ifconfig enp4s0
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.54.141  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.54.255
        ether 00:26:2d:24:91:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 47559414  bytes 8105358582 (8.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 9  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 126168339  bytes 183503412184 (183.5 GB)
        TX errors 1  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18
```

**ip outout:**

```
$ ip -s -h link show enp4s0
4: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:2d:24:91:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    8.11G      47.6M    0       9       0       3.38k
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    184G       126M     1       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `ifconfig` and `ip` show stats in appropriate unit depending on the amount of data to be displayed. Can you provide outputs showing before and after unit rollover?

Here's output from Ubuntu 16.04.4 x86_64 server:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

$ uname -p
x86_64
```

**ifconfig output**

```
$ ifconfig enp94s0f1
enp94s0f1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:ac:9e:e7:a9:cd  
          inet addr:196.196.195.10  Bcast:196.196.195.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11694856562 errors:0 dropped:38446 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10658263823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6448839112903 (6.4 TB)  TX bytes:4392568782445 (4.3 TB)
```

**ip output**

```
$ ip -s -h link show enp94s0f1
3: enp94s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:ac:9e:e7:a9:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    6.45T      11.7G    0       38.4k   0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    4.39T      10.7G    0       0       0       0
```